# Get-NetFirewallRule is very slow

Tags: powershell

The `Get-NetFirewallRule` method checks the status for about half second. This is a very long time when I need to check more than a hundred names in the firewall.

```
# About a minute checked this

0..100 | % { Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $_ }
```

Can I speed up this method? Thanks

Comment: Retrieve all rules once with `$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule` then filter by name in the script itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is faster to get all rules first. Then query the retrieved rules based on your criteria.

```
# Storing Rules in Variable First
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule
$rules | Where DisplayName -in 0..100

# Using the pipeline only 
Get-NetFirewallRule | Where DisplayName -in 0..100
```

**Performance Test:**

```
# One Rule At a Time
Measure-Command {0..10 |% { get-netfirewallrule -displayname $_ }}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 9
Milliseconds      : 877
Ticks             : 98770423
TotalDays         : 0.000114317619212963
TotalHours        : 0.00274362286111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.164617371666667
TotalSeconds      : 9.8770423
TotalMilliseconds : 9877.0423

# Get All Rules First
Measure-Command {$rules = Get-netfirewallrule; $rules | where displayname -in 0..10}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 44
Ticks             : 10440671
TotalDays         : 1.20841099537037E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000290018638888889
TotalMinutes      : 0.0174011183333333
TotalSeconds      : 1.0440671
TotalMilliseconds : 1044.0671
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I guess it's not indexed by name or displayname?  This is the wmi class it uses.  I'm not sure it's worth delving into, but fyi.

```
Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetFirewallRule -Namespace Root\StandardCimv2 -filter 'creationclassname="MSFT|FW|FirewallRule|vm-monitoring-dcom"'
```

The firewall rules are stored in the registry, btw.

There's various get-netfirewall*filter commands that make accessing certain info faster, but not name or displayname.

You can try making your own hashtable of the displaynames.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in a job, it will get way faster:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  0..100 | % { Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $_ }
}
$job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```